# WUBI INstal problem - Windows 7

Tags: wubi

I have tried to use the WUBI install for 14.04. All appears to go well until towards the end the install starts to completely remove items. These items are things such as Firefox and rhythmbox etc. When the install has finished and the system reboots for finalisation the Ubuntu OS load states there is a serious error on the disk and it cannot mount the volume. 
The Ubuntu directory that is left on the disk after the install looks pretty empty though does include directories such disks.
Any ideas are welcome.
PS. I have uninstalled Ubuntu using windows without problem.

Comment: Have u tried downloading a new copy of the ISO??
It's probably corrupted or something.
It could be also a problem with your hard drive. Self test it to confirm.

Comment: The hard drive is just fine. I have copied the WUBI.exe on to my hard drive for the install as this is what was recommended elsewhere. I also have 14.04 on dvd that I have downloaded. This does allow me to run a full demo without error. I don't want to install Ubuntu alongside windows until I am happy with it.

Comment: Have you tried launching it with admin rights??

Comment: I'll try that now.

Comment: Absolutely no difference. WUBI runs, I enter userid and password etc and then it copies the ISO. It then restarts and Ubuntu installation starts. It runs through the full installation up to configuring hardware all quite normally.

Comment: It then runs the boot loader section and then GRUB and post-installation. At this point it starts to remove things such as kpartx, xfsprogs, language packs, ubiquity, python, capser etc. It then completes installation and reboots the system for the second time. At this point Ubuntu fails with a 'serious desk error' when trying to mount NTFS volumes I think. The Ubuntu drectory looks pretty sparse. It includes 3 sub-dirs (disks, install and winboot). The grub folder inside disks/boot/is empty. At the top level is ubuntu and uninstall ubuntu. My machine is not an AMD but Intel (8 core)

Comment: I've tried installing as 32 bit as well. I don't think WUBI likes me. The only 64 bit iso I can find is AMD. Does that make a difference for 64 bit x86 processors?